Cannot build Boost Library on Windows 11
I am on Windows 11, and I cannot build Boost C++ library.
I installed successfully Microsoft Visual Sutdio 2022, downloaded boost1.83.0, unzipped it, did from the Microsoft Visual Studio Command Prompt
C:\boost_1_83_0>bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local
Found with vswhere C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
Found with vswhere C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
Call_If_Exists "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat"  AMD64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.10.5
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
###
### Using 'vc143' toolset.
###

C:\boost_1_83_0\tools\build\src\engine>"cl" /nologo -TP /wd4996 /wd4675 /EHs /GR /Zc:throwingNew /O2 /Ob2 /W3 /MD /Zc:forScope /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:inline /Gw /favor:blend /Feb2   -DNDEBUG  builtins.cpp class.cpp command.cpp compile.cpp constants.cpp cwd.cpp debug.cpp debugger.cpp execcmd.cpp execnt.cpp execunix.cpp filent.cpp filesys.cpp fileunix.cpp frames.cpp function.cpp glob.cpp hash.cpp hcache.cpp hdrmacro.cpp headers.cpp jam.cpp jamgram.cpp lists.cpp make.cpp make1.cpp md5.cpp mem.cpp modules.cpp native.cpp object.cpp option.cpp output.cpp parse.cpp pathnt.cpp pathsys.cpp pathunix.cpp regexp.cpp rules.cpp scan.cpp search.cpp jam_strings.cpp startup.cpp subst.cpp sysinfo.cpp timestamp.cpp variable.cpp w32_getreg.cpp modules/order.cpp modules/path.cpp modules/property-set.cpp modules/regex.cpp modules/sequence.cpp modules/set.cpp /link kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib
builtins.cpp
class.cpp
command.cpp
compile.cpp
constants.cpp
cwd.cpp
debug.cpp
debugger.cpp
execcmd.cpp
execnt.cpp
execunix.cpp
filent.cpp
filesys.cpp
fileunix.cpp
frames.cpp
function.cpp
glob.cpp
hash.cpp
hcache.cpp
hdrmacro.cpp
Generating Code...
Compiling...
headers.cpp
jam.cpp
jamgram.cpp
lists.cpp
make.cpp
make1.cpp
md5.cpp
mem.cpp
modules.cpp
native.cpp
object.cpp
option.cpp
output.cpp
parse.cpp
pathnt.cpp
pathsys.cpp
pathunix.cpp
regexp.cpp
rules.cpp
scan.cpp
Generating Code...
Compiling...
search.cpp
jam_strings.cpp
startup.cpp
subst.cpp
sysinfo.cpp
timestamp.cpp
variable.cpp
w32_getreg.cpp
order.cpp
path.cpp
property-set.cpp
regex.cpp
sequence.cpp
set.cpp
Generating Code...

C:\boost_1_83_0\tools\build\src\engine>dir *.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1026-75B0

 Directory of C:\boost_1_83_0\tools\build\src\engine

08/07/2024  12:17 AM           253,440 b2.exe
               1 File(s)        253,440 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  157,039,542,272 bytes free

Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam for msvc...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    .\b2

To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:

    - Command line help:
    .\b2 --help

    - Getting started guide:
    http://boost.org/more/getting_started/windows.html

    - Boost.Build documentation:
    http://www.boost.org/build/


and then when I do b2 I get the following errors ...
C:\boost_1_83_0>b2.exe
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : none (cached) [1]
    - default architecture     : none (cached) [1]

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - x86                      : no [2]
    - arm                      : no [2]
    - mips1                    : no [2]
    - power                    : no [2]
    - sparc                    : no [2]
    - has synchronization.lib  : no [2]
error: No best alternative for libs/context/build/asm_sources with <abi>ms <address-model>32 <asynch-exceptions>off <binary-format>pe <context-impl>fcontext <coverage>off <debug-store>object <debug-symbols>on <embed-manifest-via>linker <embed-manifest>on <exception-handling>on <extern-c-nothrow>off <inlining>off <link>static <midl-robust>yes <midl-stubless-proxy>yes <optimization>off <os>NT <pch>on <preserve-test-targets>on <profiling>off <python-debugging>off <relevant>abi <relevant>address-model <relevant>architecture <relevant>binary-format <relevant>toolset <rtti>on <runtime-debugging>on <runtime-link>shared <stdlib>native <strip>off <target-os>windows <testing.execute>on <threadapi>win32 <threading>multi <toolset-msvc:version>14.3 <toolset>msvc <variant>debug <vectorize>off <visibility>hidden <warnings-as-errors>off <warnings>on <windows-api>desktop
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>qcc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>loongarch <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>riscv <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>riscv <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>s390x <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>s390x <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>embarcadero
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>borland
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>embarcadero
    no match: <abi>x32 <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>x32 <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>x32 <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
    no match: <abi>sysv <architecture>arm+x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
    - has std::atomic_ref      : no [2]
    - has statx                : no [2]
    - has statx syscall        : no [2]
    - has BCrypt API           : no [2]
    - is Windows CE            : no [2]
    - has init_priority attribute : no [2]
    - has stat::st_blksize     : no [2]
    - has stat::st_mtim        : no [2]
    - has stat::st_mtimensec   : no [2]
    - has stat::st_mtimespec   : no [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtim    : no [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtimensec : no [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtimespec : no [2]
    - has fdopendir(O_NOFOLLOW) : no [2]
    - has dirent::d_type       : no [2]
    - has POSIX *at APIs       : no [2]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no [2]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no [3]
    - has_icu builds           : no [2]
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-graph_parallel" to bjam.
    - zlib                     : no  (cached) [4]
    - bzip2                    : no  (cached) [4]
    - lzma                     : no  (cached) [4]
    - zstd                     : no  (cached) [4]
    - has_lzma_cputhreads builds : no [2]
    - cxx11_constexpr          : no [2]
    - cxx11_constexpr          : no [3]
    - iconv (libc)             : no [2]
    - iconv (separate)         : no [2]
    - icu                      : no [2]
    - iconv (libc)             : no [3]
    - iconv (separate)         : no [3]
    - icu                      : no [3]
    - native atomic int32 supported : no [2]
    - mips                     : no [2]
    - has message compiler     : no [2]
    - native syslog supported  : no [2]
    - pthread supports robust mutexes : no [2]
    - gcc visibility           : no [2]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : no [2]
    - gcc visibility           : no [3]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : no [3]
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
warning: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration
note: failed.  See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html
note: for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to
note: suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets
    - libbacktrace builds      : no [2]
    - libbacktrace builds      : no [3]
    - addr2line builds         : no [2]
    - addr2line builds         : no [3]
    - WinDbg builds            : no [2]
    - WinDbg builds            : no [3]
    - WinDbgCached builds      : no [2]
    - WinDbgCached builds      : no [3]
    - BOOST_COMP_GNUC >= 4.3.0 : no [2]
    - x86                      : no [5]
    - arm                      : no [5]
    - mips1                    : no [5]
    - power                    : no [5]
    - sparc                    : no [5]
    - has synchronization.lib  : no [5]
error: No best alternative for libs/context/build/asm_sources with <abi>ms <address-model>32 <asynch-exceptions>off <binary-format>pe <context-impl>fcontext <coverage>off <debug-store>object <debug-symbols>off <embed-manifest-via>linker <embed-manifest>on <exception-handling>on <extern-c-nothrow>off <inlining>full <link>static <midl-robust>yes <midl-stubless-proxy>yes <optimization>speed <os>NT <pch>on <preserve-test-targets>on <profiling>off <python-debugging>off <relevant>abi <relevant>address-model <relevant>architecture <relevant>binary-format <relevant>toolset <rtti>on <runtime-debugging>off <runtime-link>shared <stdlib>native <strip>off <target-os>windows <testing.execute>on <threadapi>win32 <threading>multi <toolset-msvc:version>14.3 <toolset>msvc <variant>release <vectorize>off <visibility>hidden <warnings-as-errors>off <warnings>on <windows-api>desktop
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>qcc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>32 <architecture>arm <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>aapcs <address-model>64 <architecture>arm <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>loongarch <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>o32 <address-model>32 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>n64 <address-model>64 <architecture>mips <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>power <binary-format>xcoff <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>power <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>riscv <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>riscv <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>s390x <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>s390x <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>embarcadero
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>borland
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>darwin
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>clang-win
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>msvc
    no match: <abi>ms <address-model>64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>pe <threading>multi <toolset>embarcadero
    no match: <abi>x32 <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>clang
    no match: <abi>x32 <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>gcc
    no match: <abi>x32 <address-model>32 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>elf <threading>multi <toolset>intel
    no match: <abi>sysv <address-model>32_64 <architecture>x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
    no match: <abi>sysv <architecture>arm+x86 <binary-format>mach-o <threading>multi
    - has std::atomic_ref      : no [5]
    - has statx                : no [5]
    - has statx syscall        : no [5]
    - has BCrypt API           : no [5]
    - is Windows CE            : no [5]
    - has init_priority attribute : no [5]
    - has stat::st_blksize     : no [5]
    - has stat::st_mtim        : no [5]
    - has stat::st_mtimensec   : no [5]
    - has stat::st_mtimespec   : no [5]
    - has stat::st_birthtim    : no [5]
    - has stat::st_birthtimensec : no [5]
    - has stat::st_birthtimespec : no [5]
    - has fdopendir(O_NOFOLLOW) : no [5]
    - has dirent::d_type       : no [5]
    - has POSIX *at APIs       : no [5]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no [5]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no [6]
    - has_icu builds           : no [5]

Do you know what is wrong here, and what I should do to get, say, the file libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-sgd-x64-1_83.lib properly built ?
Thank you :)

You say MingW, but the logs are pretty consistently saying MSVC....

As you can see generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam for msvc. boost thinks you want to use msvc not mingw.

And one could add, why not use pacman to install boost itself? Do you have any particular reason to build it from source? Using pacman is certainly the easy option if you want boost for mingw.

99% of the time you don't really need to "build" Boost beyond just unzipping it. The major portions of Boost are "header only libraries" that just require the caller to #include the required headers with no additional work. Are you absolutely certain you need to build the Boost libraries vs just unzipping it?

@selbie, I am. I need filesystem.

@all, following your suggestion on pacman, I downloaded and installed Msys2 from here https://www.msys2.org/, then from the msys2 console I ran pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-boost. Is this correct? The installation ended without issues. Where do I find the .h and the .lib files ? I need files such as 'libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-sgd-x64-1_83.lib' and from the pacman installation it is totally unclear if and where they were created.

@drescherjm, the package  https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-boost?repo=ucrt64 does not install the file libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-sgd-x64-1_83.lib, but just some .a file, it is not what I need.
Can anyone tell me how to get libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-sgd-x64-1_83.lib properly built ?

libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-sgd-x64-1_83.lib again you are mentioning msvc. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? I ask because it seems you have some wrong instructions or something. Remember there is compatibility between mscv and MinGW for c  based code but not really c++ because of several reasons. For c++ you should build everything with the same compiler and not mix MinGW and msvc.

@drescherjm, like I said, I want to build file libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-sgd-x64-1_83.lib. That's it. This is for msvc. I don't know how to do it, and the links provided in this discussion do not allow me to do it. Do you know how to achieve this ?

The second line of your question says: "I installed successfully MingW, downloaded boost1.83.0, unzipped it, did" This is were the confusion comes from for everyone who has tried to help. If you want msvc then you were on the correct path (except for the MinGW installation which has nothing to do with building boost for msvc) and we need to look deeper to understand where the error occurred.

Interestingly I will attempt build boost for msvc 2022 in a few minutes in the process of building my own code. I just got qt6.7.2 to successfully build after disabling qtopcua.

@drescherjm, I understand. I revised my original question: the outputs of bootstrap and of b2 are there, and I hope that they will allow to understand where the problem is.

b2.exe -j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% --without-python --without-mpi  address-model=64 --toolset=msvc-14.3 --build-type=complete stage install worked for me for boost-1.84.0. I did use 2 additional arguments but those are specific to my folder structure on the machine I am building: --build-dir=X:/x64.21/VC.143/Libraries/Boost-1.84.0/build --prefix=X:/x64.21/VC.143/Libraries/Boost-1.84.0

@drescherjm it does not work for me

@drescherjm do you have 32 or 64 bit version of Windows installed ?

address-model=64 means 64 bit. I am starting with the source code and not a binary package: https://archives.boost.io/release/1.84.0/source/boost_1_84_0.7z

Same here, but it does not work.

Sorry I originally wrote too soon and my original solution did not work.
The issue we're running into is documented as a boost issue and resolved as a b2 issue.
The summary of the change within boost is to patch msvc.jam as in the b2 pull request linked above
--- a/tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam    Thu Apr 07 07:02:44 2022
+++ b/tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam    Tue Sep 24 22:17:24 2024
@@ -1113,7 +1113,7 @@
         }
         else
         {
-            if [ MATCH "(14.3)" : $(version) ]
+            if [ MATCH "(14.[34])" : $(version) ]
             {
                 if $(.debug-configuration)
                 {
@@ -1292,7 +1292,7 @@
             # version from the path.
             # FIXME: We currently detect both Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 and
             # 9.0express as 9.0 here.
-            if [ MATCH "(MSVC\\\\14.3)" : $(command) ]
+            if [ MATCH "(MSVC\\\\14.[34])" : $(command) ]
             {
                 version = 14.3 ;
             }

I was doing this on a Windows CI system (no patch support), so implemented it successfully against 1.79.0 using the following Powershell incantation(s):
(Get-Content tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam) -replace '(MATCH.*14\.)3', '$1[34]' | Out-File tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam.2

Move-Item -Force tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam.2 tools/build/src/tools/msvc.jam

Unlike my previous suggestion - no special arguments are required - follow the normal build process.  However to avoid incorrect cached info from your previous failures pass the --reconfigure flag to b2
.\b2.exe --reconfigure install        ... your other options too

Hope it works for you
